# Tag Editing - [humid] & [arid]

Tags: discussion, tags

Judging by time stamps, it appears the OP for the question *[What is the definition for a hyper-humid area?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24427/what-is-the-definition-for-a-hyper-humid-area)* created the `arid` and `humid` tags. Neither tag has any guidance.

The long extant `humidity` tag would be more appropriate for the question than a newly created `humid` tag, I have edited the question to reflect this. Could those with authority to do so, please remove the `humid` tag as it is a meaningless tag?

Similarly could the `arid` tag be changed to `aridity`?

Comment: I'm for removing the [tag:humid] tag. As for the `aridity` proposal, I noticed that we have already [tag:desert], [tag:desertification] and [tag:drought], aren't those enough to cover the 'aridity' topic?

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival: If we can do without an `aridity` tag I'm okay with that, but what tags would you apply to the question that initiated this issue?

Comment: Good remark, I'm not sure... But the question is actually about (hyper) humidity, not aridity, which is just used as an example of index.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need `aridity`.  An arid area is just an area with low humidity, so humidity is enough.

Answer (score 1):

In geomorphology an arid zone is a field of study with different geomorphology characteristic structures as it can be glacial or periglacial. I agree `aridity` is not needed, but maybe we need a tag `arid-zone` or so.